# Input and if-else statements are doing weird stuff

Tags: python

I made a number guessing game in Python and what it does is it asks for a number between 1 and 100. You get to choose between easy and hard level. Easy level has 10 and hard has 5 chances. The problem is if you give level input anything other than easy or hard (uppercase variations included) it does some weird stuff. I need a solution to that. Here's the code.

```
import random
print("Welcome to the number guessing game.")
random_number: int = random.randint(0, 101)
print("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100.")

total_chances = 0

game_level = input("Type a difficulty. Type 'easy' or 'hard': ").lower()

if game_level == 'easy':
    total_chances = 10
elif game_level == 'hard':
    total_chances = 5
else:
    print("Please make sure that you typed the correct command")

is_game_over = False

while not is_game_over:
    print(f"You have {total_chances} chances remaining to guess the number.")
    guess_a_number = int(input("Guess a number: "))

    if guess_a_number == random_number:
        is_game_over = True
        print(f"You got it!! The answer was {random_number}. \nYou win.")
    elif guess_a_number > random_number:
        total_chances -= 1
        print("Too high.\nGuess again.")
    elif guess_a_number < random_number:
        total_chances -= 1
        print("Too low.\nGuess again.")
    else:
        print("Guess a number. Please make a correct numerical input.")

    if total_chances <= 0:
        is_game_over = True
        print("You ran out of chances. You lose!!")
        print(f"The answer was {random_number}")
```

Comment: What do you called `weird stuff`?

Comment: What is the weird stuff you are talking about? Is there some errors in printing? Or the guessing part?

Comment: If they enter something that isn't a valid integer, you're going to get an exception.  You need to be prepared to handle that exception.

Comment: Actually when I type something else for game level input, eg. laksjf. Then the program would not end. But it is fixed now. I was unable to get some good topic for the question. Can you recommend one.

Comment: It's working perfectly for me dude what's problem

Comment: The problem is when you type something like lafjskl when it asks for choosing game level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in the code is that when a user types in a wrong game level, then it just prints the warning message, and then move on with `total_chances` being 0 and `is_game_over` beinig `False`. Since the latter is `False`, the `while` loop, i.e., the guessing stage is run anyway, *even when `total_chances` is zero*!

Try

```py
is_game_over = False
if game_level == 'easy':
    total_chances = 10
elif game_level == 'hard':
    total_chances = 5
else:
    print("Please make sure that you typed the correct command")
    is_game_over = True
```

This will end the game when a user types in wrong difficulty level; since `is_game_over` is `True`, the `while` loop is skipped.

Comment: I would raise a ValueError, re-prompt the question, or just use `return`. This is an input error and not running out of chances, which is what `is_game_over` seems to be for.

Comment: I agree; I would do the latter with a `while` loop. But as the OP was not clear on what he/she wanted, I'll leave it to the OP's job.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a while loop to get an input until a correct difficulty level is entered like this:

```
total_chances = 0
while(total_chances==0):
    game_level = input("Type a difficulty. Type 'easy' or 'hard': ").lower()
    
    if game_level == 'easy':
        total_chances = 10
    elif game_level == 'hard':
        total_chances = 5
    else:
        print("Please make sure that you typed the correct command")
```